# Как перебирает значения цикл for в Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, for

Всем привет! Пока я занимался своим проектом, я заметил, что если прибавить число к переменной из цикла `for`, то он начинает себя вести *"не соовсем адекватно"*.

Обычный, непримечательный цикл `for`:

```
for x in range(1,10):
    logging.info('X = {}'.format(x))
```

На выходе стандартная ситуация:

```
[03.14.2019 18:17:40 | INFO]: X = 1
[03.14.2019 18:17:40 | INFO]: X = 2
[03.14.2019 18:17:40 | INFO]: X = 3
[03.14.2019 18:17:40 | INFO]: X = 4
[03.14.2019 18:17:40 | INFO]: X = 5
[03.14.2019 18:17:40 | INFO]: X = 6
[03.14.2019 18:17:40 | INFO]: X = 7
[03.14.2019 18:17:40 | INFO]: X = 8
[03.14.2019 18:17:40 | INFO]: X = 9
```

Но стоит только сделать так:

```
for x in range(1,10):
    x += 7
    logging.info('X = {}'.format(x))
```

То мой Python 3.5 сходит с ума:

```
[03.14.2019 18:18:03 | INFO]: X = 8
[03.14.2019 18:18:03 | INFO]: X = 9
[03.14.2019 18:18:03 | INFO]: X = 10
[03.14.2019 18:18:03 | INFO]: X = 11
[03.14.2019 18:18:03 | INFO]: X = 12
[03.14.2019 18:18:03 | INFO]: X = 13
[03.14.2019 18:18:03 | INFO]: X = 14
[03.14.2019 18:18:03 | INFO]: X = 15
[03.14.2019 18:18:03 | INFO]: X = 16
```

В чём собственно причина данной проблемы и как можно её решить?

Comment: @Эникейщик упс, опечаточка при вставке в вопрос :)

Comment: В чем неадекватность и где проблема?

Comment: @Эникейщик ну, по идее, цикл `for` должен работать до 10.

Comment: У Вас 2 одинаковых куска кода. Я так понимаю что Вы говорите про строчку x +=7.  Ничего там не ломается , все работает правильно. Вы зашли в цикл , x=1 . в теле цикла вы прибавили сделали x = x +7, будет 8. Следующая итерация - x =2  в теле цикла вы прибавили сделали x = x +7, будет 9. Все правильно работает

Comment: Он и работает. Про +7 вы уже забыли?

Comment: @Timoha_Timohavich Вы зашли в цикл первый раз. x=1, прибавили 7. x=8 , вывели на экран. Вторая итерация, x=2 , прибавили 7 . x =9, вывели на экран

Comment: Читайте ответ, там все написано. range() не сравнивает значение переменной с границами, а выдает все. Если вы сделаете к теле цикла x -=1, то он не станет бесконечным, а также закончится после 10 итераций.

Comment: Вы мне починили логику, спасибо :D. Пойду тогда изменю цикл, чтобы он не зависел от такой оплошности моих ручёнок

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На самом деле, все правильно.
Когда интерпретатор обрабатывает строку `for x in range(1,10):` вычисляются все значения `x` по которым надо пройти. 
То есть, список выражений вычисляется один раз, а затем набор выполняется один раз для каждого элемента,

В вашем случае список выражений будет `1, 2, 3 ..`. 
Потом вы меняете `x` внутри цикла, но на новой итерации цикла `x` снова принимает значения из заранее вычисленного списка выражений, и вы снова его увеличиваете.

Первая итерация:

```
for x in range(1,10): # x = 1
    x += 7 # x = 1 + 7 = 8
    logging.info('X = {}'.format(x))
```

Вторая итерация:

```
for x in range(1,10): # x = 2
    x += 7 # x = 2 + 7 = 9
    logging.info('X = {}'.format(x))
```

Ну и [ссылка на доку](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for)