# Можно ли итерировать параметр цикла 'for' внутри цикла?

Tags: python, for, итераторы

Понятно, что лобовой вариант не проходит:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    i=4
```

На печать выйдет:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Однако, вопрос остается - можно как-то манипулировать `i` так, чтобы цикл "воспринимал" желаемые изменения?
Или в этом случае  -  только цикл `while`?
Я имею ввиду попытки типа:

```
r5 = range(5)
for i in r5:
    print(i)
    for i in range(4):
        r5.__iter__()
```

но так оно не работает (
-----------------------------------------------ЗАРАБОТАЛО--после ответа @Александр:

```
d = [2,7,9,10,11,15,19,20,21,30,31]
m_d = [[x,0] for x in d]

mark = 0
_ = iter(range(len(m_d)-1))
for i in _:   
    while (m_d[i+1][0]-m_d[i][0] <2) and (i<len(m_d)-2):
        m_d[i][1] = mark
        next(_)
        i+=1
    m_d[i][1] = mark
    mark +=1
#  проверка на то, что последние элемент входит в маркируемый блок
if m_d[len(m_d)-1][0] - m_d[len(m_d)-2][0] <2:
    m_d[len(m_d)-1][1] = m_d[len(m_d)-2][1]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(m_d)
```

Дает желаемое

```
[[2, 0],
 [7, 1],
 [9, 2],
 [10, 2],
 [11, 2],
 [15, 3],
 [19, 4],
 [20, 4],
 [21, 4],
 [30, 5],
 [31, 5]]
```

Так ли плох мой код теперь?

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, а вам зачем?

Comment: @andreymal думаю очевидно. В цикле   'while'  приходится ручками реализовывать итерирование а-ля  'for'. 
может некая детализация задачи поможет понять.
мне нужно пройти по списку чисел и найти места "уплотнений" и пометить их маркером. Ну что то вроде кластеризации.
То есть я дошел до места уплотнения и начинаю новый цикл "пока" уплотнение не закончится, однако продолжая итерировать по списку....

Comment: Ничего не понял, если честно) Но в любом случае, как уже успели написать в ответе, цикл for изначально не предназначен для этого

Comment: Я не очень понял ваш пример, но, кажется, вам нужно просто нужно завести булевскую переменную, которая будет говорить, находитесь вы сейчас внутри "уплотнения" или нет. И в зависимости от её значения выполнять ту или иную логику.

Comment: немного [о работе цикла for](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/956553/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-for-%D0%B2-python-3-5/956556#956556)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если вы всё-таки упорно не хотите использовать `while` и вам нужно просто пропустить часть значений, и вы это хотите сделать именно с помощью манипулирования объектом после in, то можно сделать так:

```
r100 = iter(range(100))
for i in r100:
    print(i)
    for j in range(3):
        next(r100)
```

Этот цикл пройдётся по числам до 100, но после каждого напечатанного числа будет пропускать следующие три.

Но всё таки гораздо правильнее не хачить итераторы, а сделать например так:

```
skip = 0

for i in range(100):

    if skip:
        skip -= 1
    else:
        print(i)
        skip = 3
```

Этот код сделает то же самое, но его проще читать, и меньше вероятность, что он станет причиной трудноотлавливаемой ошибки.

Comment: Буду надеяться, что галочка поставлена за вторую часть ответа)

Comment: я дополнил вопрос неправильным примером своего решения.
в том и дело, что надо не пропускать а итерировать ))

Comment: конечно в жизни-то я сделал через фор, добавил переменную проверки состояния-флаг, чекаю ифами, сбрасываю флаг когда надо, однако хотелось именн дать галочку за первую часть решения ))

Comment: @Александр! 
,
Мой код опасен?
так не принято?
это противоречит дзен Python?
.
Был бы приятно получить вашу оценку

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, я бы сказал что он просто более запутан и в нём используются действия, которые другие программисты сочтут контринтуитивными. В совместном с другими людьми проекте так лучше не делать.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте сформулируем задачу.

> Разбить список на группы, так, чтобы все последовательные числа попали в одну группу

```py
[[2], [7], [9,10,11], [15], [19,20,21], [30,31]]
```

> Промаркировать все числа в каждой группе номером соответствующей группы и слить обратно в список

```py
[(0,[2]), (1,[7]), (2,[9,10,11]), (3,[15]), (4,[19,20,21]), (5,[30,31])]
[[2,0], [7,1], [9,2], [10,2], [11,2], [15,3], [19,4], [20,4], [21,4], [30,5], [31,5]]
```

Группировать будем используя такую хитрость:

> Из каждого элемента вычтем его индекс, полученный результат будет ключом группы

```py
[2-0, 7-1, 9-2, 10-3, 11-4, 15-5, 19-6, 20-7, 21-8, 30-9, 31-10]
[2, 6, 7,7,7, 10, 13,13,13, 21,21]
```

Задача целиком решается так (правда группировать будем индексы элементов, а не сами элементы):

```py
from itertools import groupby


def markgroups(elems):
    def getkey(idx):
        "По номеру элемента возвращает ключ его группы"
        return elems[idx] - idx

    groups = (group
              for _, group in groupby(range(len(elems)), key=getkey))

    return [[elems[idx], group_idx]
            for group_idx, group in enumerate(groups)
            for idx in group]


print(markgroups([2, 7, 9, 10, 11, 15, 19, 20, 21, 30, 31]))
```

Не стану утверждать, что это решение очень легко понять новичку, но новичок состояние не перманентное - пара недель практики, и все станет понятно и естественно.

Однако оцените, несколько просто можно сформулировать задачу, и также просто описать ее решение естественным языком.

**UPD:** Обновил решение, чтобы оно не создавало промежуточные списки. Хотел сделать так изначально, но решил что со списками будет проще понять, как это работает.

Тест производительности на списке из ~800000 элементов (примерно каждый пятый пропущен):

```
inplace:    0.4143 s
markgroups: 0.2756 s
```

https://ideone.com/Kv3F8U

Comment: ну никто не сбрасывал со счетов производительность.
так я работаю в pandas как говорят  "inplace", а так роиходится лепить в памяти списки что весьма затратно.
Я и ищу - разумный компромис между ясностью формулировки, прозрачностью кода (через 3 месяца надо вспомнить)  и скоростью работы.
.
…. Потом же мне с каждой группой надо анализ делать   ...  Те же свлдные таблицы например.                                          Быстрое правильное решение с "ифами" и флагами у меня было изначально. Хотелось немного больше семантичности…
Благодарю за участие )

Comment: Для `pandas` inplace оправдан, там обработкой занимается быстрый нативный код, который работает с нативными же типами данных. В чистом же `python` выгода только в размере, не в скорости, но и это поправимо. Обновил решение, добавил сравнение производительности.

Comment: Это круть!!
я так не думал раньше.

Comment: Если `m_d` это тоже промежуточный результат, который вдальнейшем нужно будет последовательно обойти один раз (не обращаясь к элементам по индексам), то для экономии памяти можно заменить `return [...]` на `return (...)`. тогда вместо списка получится еще один ленивый генератор, как и `groups` и каждый `group` внутри `groups`

Answer (score 1):

Нет, нельзя.

Суть цикла `for` в том, что он итерируется по объекту идущему после `in` и на каждом шаге присваивает очередное значение переменной, идущей до `in`.

То есть что бы вы не сделали внутри итерации, вначале следующей переменная всё равно получит очередное значение.

Так что да, чтобы изменения в переменной сохранялись, нужно использовать цикл `while`.

Comment: печалька. а можно что то в цикле делать с объектом который идет после `in`.  В этом и есть суть вопроса

Comment: @VasylKolomiets другие программисты больно побьют за изменение объекта после `in`

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, можно, но лучше так не извращаться, а использовать while.

Comment: я дополню вопрос примером, мож есть более красивый вариант, чем я нарисовал

Comment: эх, а в си-подобных языках можно :)